# Templating in Postmaster / Templating in General (Super Simple)

Tags: templates, postmaster

I am trying to figure out how to simply post channel information in a Postmaster email template and for the life of me I cannot figure out why I cannot. Lets say I have a news channel. Why wont this work?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have tried this with many different template variables and I cannot tell if its postmaster or my template code failing.

Comment: Have you tried adding `dynamic="no"` to your `channel:entries` tag?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need `dynamic="no"` in your channel entries tag?

Comment: Argh, sorry Derek, didn't see your comment, @David, what he said! lol